# Porting Windows Store apps to Windows RT

Tags: windows-runtime

Problems of what categories may arise when porting existing Windows Store applications to enble them running on Windows RT tablets? I'm especially interested in C# XAML games, but other situations are relevant as well (C++, JavaScript).

Comment: "What are all of the problems that I might run into doing X?" is too broad a question for Stack Overflow.  It is not possible to answer definitively or objectively, and answers are likely to be far too general to be of any use to anyone.

Comment: Categories of incompatibilities between Win32 and ARM is what is of most interest. Broad, but useful IMO.

Comment: See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  "Open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site."

Comment: The reason for asking is that it is difficult to find a tablet for testing during development thus a checklist would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Hovever, many undesirable kinds of questions are extremely useful for novices and experienced devs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No porting considerations apply.  Managed apps already dealt with processor architecture differences smoothly thanks to the jitter.  Which made the difference between a 32-bit and a 64-bit operating system and processor invisible, as long as your pinvoke was kosher and you didn't have a dependency on an ancient 32-bit component.

The extends to Windows RT the same way, it has an ARM jitter if the machine has an ARM core.  WinRT is architecture agnostic.  Having trouble with a dependency on pinvoke or COM is eliminated as well, you wouldn't have been able to get your app published in the Store when you have such a dependency.  WACK would have warned you about that early.

It just works.  It was designed that way.

Comment: Can't upvote, but would do that if could. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Hans already said, I'd like to point out two things, you need to consider:

- Dependency on external native libraries: All of them already need to be Windows Store compliant otherwise WACK validation will fail. But they also need to be available for all three processor architectures: as soon as you start using them, you'll need to create three for different builds of your app (x86, x64 and ARM) instead of a common one for all three.
- Don't forget about performance, particularly because you're asking about games. Hardware in ARM devices is typically slower so you might run into performance problems on ARM devices which you won't encounter on Intel devices. Unfortunately the only way to check for this is to test it on a physical device.